# Metal fuel lines jiggle (wobble)

Tags: repair, fuel-line

The other day I found out that the fuel line and breather line (both metal hoses) are jiggling (quite much) at the back (for example if I jiggle them above the rear stabilizer bar). There is also a plastic hose separator which is broken, but I'll 3D print one, so no worries here.

These are my questions:

1. **Are the lines suppose to jiggle/be wobbly or should they be firmly snapped to the body?**
2. If answer to 1. is NO then, is there any way one can tighten them at home with ordinary jack (without a service lift)? As far as I've seen, I couldn't access the nut from below. Is there another place I can access it?

This seems quite dangerous to me.

Volvo s80 2009 D5244T5 M66 w/ 330.000km

EDIT:
Plaese look at the video below for actual jiggling of the lines. Also, can anyone please identify, what could that annoying sound at the end of the video could be source of (I've pushed the back of the car up and down).

[Fuel lines video](https://youtu.be/8z_5MTe2bi4)

Comment: A picture would be helpful to understand the situation better.

Comment: Ok, will do a GIF image tonight.

Comment: Look for lose, broken or missing attachment clips.

Comment: They are broken, but I don't think they should "wooble" that much. Do you think it's enough they are connected one to each other? Or should they be connected to each other and also the body?

Comment: The two white clips are broken, there's your problem.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. It also says in the original post. I am afraid that even if the clips are on, the line is jiggling to much. Shouldn't this be tighter (I'm talking about the thread)?